# Shopping Cart Using Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, session, servlets, shopping-cart

I have a simple shopping cart code that add products from a drop-down list of games in an html page. I edited the html page, removed the drop down list and added an 'add to cart' button for each game. So I have been trying to edit the cart to add the games whenever any 'add to cart' button is clicked but couldn't. Note that I am using jetty-9 servlets for server side code.

Please help me !!!

Here is the original cart code that worked with the drop down list:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class Cart extends HttpServlet {
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException {
        String s, goods[] = {"Fifa 15", "Battlefield 5", "GTA 6"};
        double price []={10,20,30};
        double cost;
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

        if ( session == null ) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < goods.length; i++)
        if ( session.getAttribute(goods[i]) == null )
            session.setAttribute(goods[i], new Integer(0));

        if ( (s = req.getParameter("buy")) != null ) {
            int n = ((Integer)session.getAttribute(s)).intValue();
            session.setAttribute(s, new Integer(n + 1));
        }
        out.println("<html><body><h2>Shopping Cart</h2><ul>");
        for (int i = 0; i < goods.length; i++) {
            int n = ((Integer)session.getAttribute(goods[i])).intValue();
            if ( n > 0 ){
                out.println("<li><b>" + goods[i] + "</b> : " + n +":"+ price[i] +"</li>");
                cost=n*price[i];
                out.println(cost);}
            }
        out.println("</ul></body></html>");
    }
}
```

Hers is the html page of the games:

```
<html>
Games
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form  action="http://localhost:8080/apps/Cart"method="post" >

        Fifa 15 </br> 
        <img src="images/fifa-15.jpg" width = 200 height = 300 alt="image" /></br>
        <input type="submit" value="add to cart" ></br> 

        Battlefield 4</br>
        <img src="images/battlefield-4.jpg" width = 200 height = 300 alt="image" /></br>
        <input type="submit" value="add to cart" name ="battle"></br>

        GTA 5</br>
        <img src="images/gta-5.jpg" width = 200 height = 300 alt="image" /></br>
        <input type="submit" value="add to cart" name = "gta">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally your code should be this:

```
HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);

    for (int i = 0; i < goods.length; i++) {
        if (session.getAttribute(goods[i]) == null)
            session.setAttribute(goods[i], new Integer(0));
    }

    if ((s = req.getParameter("fifa")) != null) {
        int n = ((Integer) session.getAttribute(goods[0])).intValue();
        session.setAttribute(goods[0], new Integer(n + 1));
    } else if ((s = req.getParameter("battle")) != null) {
        int n = ((Integer) session.getAttribute(goods[1])).intValue();
        session.setAttribute(goods[1], new Integer(n + 1));
    } else if ((s = req.getParameter("gta")) != null) {
        int n = ((Integer) session.getAttribute(goods[2])).intValue();
        session.setAttribute(goods[2], new Integer(n + 1));
    }
```

And html page:

```
    Fifa 15 </br> 
    <img src="images/fifa-15.jpg" width = 200 height = 300 alt="image" /></br>
    <input type="submit" value="add to cart" name = "fifa"></br> 

    Battlefield 4</br>
    <img src="images/battlefield-4.jpg" width = 200 height = 300 alt="image" /></br>
    <input type="submit" value="add to cart" name ="battle"></br>

    GTA 5</br>
    <img src="images/gta-5.jpg" width = 200 height = 300 alt="image" /></br>
    <input type="submit" value="add to cart" name = "gta">
```

After detecting which button was pressed you can choose action for each button.

Comment: still not working, the code you replace with system.out.println('fifa') was originally used to add the item from the dropdown list to the cart. but the dropdown list is not there anymore

Comment: I added id=fifa instead of name=fifa but got an error.

Comment: I tried it again and I think am on the right track. the funny thing is when pressing the button the cart page still is empty but I noticed fifa is displayed on the cmd where I am running the server. What do you think ?

Comment: You got it! If you want your product will appear in cart you need to store it in the session in proper way.

Comment: okay, fifa was displayed in the cart page, can u help me figure out the calculation to display the price as well.                                                                  if ( (s = req.getParameter("fifa")) != null ) {
   out.println("fifa");
                                                                           //int n = ((Integer)session.getAttribute(s)).intValue();
                                                             //session.setAttribute(s, new Integer(n + 1));

Comment: Price defened in 'double price[] = { 10, 20, 30 };' first value for fifa second to battle... I printed you fully working code.